# Where to store temp data during replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, temp-tables

I've just started playing around with Replicating our system and am not sure how best to handle this issue.

I want to filter data, but its not as easy as "where columnName = 'abc'".  So I'm writing a big complicated process that is determining which records from each table are going to be replicated.  I'm storing the PKs for each table in temp tables.  I envisioned that the pre_snapshot_script would create and populate these tables and the post_snapshot_script would delete them.  The filter statements for these tables then read something like "where PK in (select pk_id from temp table)"

So.  Where can I put this data?  Do I need to make persistent tables in my database in order to have them marked for replication?  I assume any #temp or ##temp tables won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're PK in (select PK from table) idea may be correct.

You're right that it would need to be a persistent table.  Can you provide a little more detail on the scenario?  Are you generating snapshots hourly/daily/weekly?  Any transactional replication going on after? What sort of logic are you using?

These answers might help illuminate other solutions or help verify that your initial path was the correct one.